# What is the right way to cite @inproceedings with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, best-practices

What is the right way to cite `@inproceedings` with biblatex?

More specifically, many computer science proceedings paper citations seem to use book titles like "Proceedings of the 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science".  How should this book title be broken down for the biblatex fields?

Here are several combinations of `booktitle`, `booksubtitle`, and `booktitleaddon`.  Which is the best practice based on the biblatex model?

```
@inproceedings{key,
  ...,
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science},
  ...
}

@inproceedings{key,
  ...,
  booktitle = {Logic in Computer Science},
  booksubtitle = {Proceedings of the 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium}, 
  ...
}

@inproceedings{key,
  ...,
  booktitle = {Logic in Computer Science},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium}, 
  ...
}
```

Comment: The first one would be the most common in my world (a mix of history/philosophy/law).  Usually, the title of the volume is pretty clearly marked in terms of what is booktitle and booksubtitle, and, more rarely, what could be put in the booktitleaddon fields.  To me, it looks like the 'subject' of this Proceedings volume is 'Logic in Computer Science', not that 'Logic in Computer Science' is the title -- but it is easier to judge by looking at the library of congress information and publication information (if any).

Comment: If you have a look at `biblatex-examples.bib` you will find that the two examples of `@inproceedings` put the "Proceedings of the blargh blub" in the `booktitleaddon` field. These entries, however, do have a proper `booktitle` which in your case is missing. Still, either put the whole title in `booktitle` (as you did in the first one) or in `booktitleaddon`. The second and third alternative look weird to me since "Logic in Computer Science" is actually part of the conference title.

Answer (score 22):

An example from `biblatex-examples.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{salam,
  author       = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor       = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title        = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  date         = {1968},
  booktitle    = {Elementary particle theory},
  booksubtitle = {Relativistic groups and analyticity},
  booktitleaddon= {Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium},
  eventdate    = {1968-05-19/1968-05-25},
  venue        = {Aspen{\"a}sgarden, Lerum},
  publisher    = {Almquist \& Wiksell},
  location     = {Stockholm},
  pages        = {367-377},
}
```

So if there is a dedicated title field, standard seems to be to put the "Proceedings of ..." part into the `(book)titleaddon` field.

It is probably best to put `2013 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science` into the `title` field, if there is no other title available - after all we do not want to have an empty `title` field.

```
@proceedings{lics,
  title        = {2013 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science},
  shorttitle   = {LICS},
  eventdate    = {2013-06-25/2013-06-28},
  venue        = {New Orleans, Louisiana},
  isbn         = {978-1-4799-0413-6},
  publisher    = {IEEE Computer Society},
  date         = {2013},
}
@inproceedings{pattinson,
  author      = {Pattinson, Dirk},
  title       = {The Logic of Exact Covers},
  subtitle    = {Completeness and Uniform Interpolation},
  crossref    = {lics},
  pages       = {418-427},
}
```

Another solution would be your third idea, though that does not reflect the title information as given in the proceedings itself.

```
@proceedings{lics,
  booktitle    = {Logic in Computer Science},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the 28th Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium}, 
  shorttitle   = {LICS},
  eventdate    = {2013-06-25/2013-06-28},
  venue        = {New Orleans, Louisiana},
  isbn         = {978-1-4799-0413-6},
  publisher    = {IEEE Computer Society},
  date         = {2013},
}
```